# How to add element at the end of added element using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").after("Add Element");
   });
});
```

How to add element at the end of added element using jquery?

Add Element

Comment: please share your html code also

Answer (score 0):

To add element as last one just use `append`:

```
$('#container').append('<p>Hello world!</p>');
```

To insert element after another one use `insertAfter`:

```
$('<p>Hello world!</p>').insertAfter('#some-other-element');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.append` function of jquery. So your code will be

```
$("p").append("Your Element");
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(){
      $("p").after("Add Element");
   });
});

Answer (score 0):

Try:using append().

```
$("p").append("Element");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..fulfils your requirement without changing your script :)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(){
      $("p").after("Add Element");
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Sample Paragraph </p>
<button>Sample button</button>
```